# I am trying to run azuracast on docker with ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, port

I am facing this error. Error response from daemon:

> driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint azuracast (921386c2563e5e74537acd9f8b3aaf1f982cb974d9af4d24387382d2771d9a12): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated

I dont know what to do

I am trying to run azuracast on docker. The container is running without any port.

Answer (score 0):

from the error `port is already allocated` means that you have another service on your machine using port 80.

To figure out what is using port 80 use `netstat -tulpn | grep :80`

you can also, change the port of the new docker container to run on a different port, by passing something like `-p 8080:80` to the docker run command.